# How to use React Native use else if Condition?

Tags: react-native

How can I use conditional statements inside react render function? Below is my sample code.

```
render() {
            return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                if(status == "En attente") {
                  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
                }
                else if (status == "En cours") {
                  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
                }
                else {
                  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
                }
              </View>
            )
          }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the ternary operator - `?`

```
render() {
    return ( <
        View style = {
            styles.container
        } >
        {(status == "En attente") ? < View style = {
            {
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                height: 50,
                width: 50
            }
        } > < /View> : ((status == "En cours") ? (<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View > ): ( < View style = {
            {
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                height: 50,
                width: 50
            }
        } > < /View>))} <
        /View>
    )
}
```

Comment: {
        (status == "En attente") ?
        (status == "En cours") ?
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
        :
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
        :
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
      }

Comment: I have a output is this formate if () {} else if () {} else {}

Comment: Final Answer is {
        (status == "En attente") ?
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View> :
        (status == "Annulé") ?
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
        :
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 50, width: 50 }}></View>
      }

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya  just modified the answer. Can you check if that works or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Use ternary operators

```
render(){
 return ((condition)? true_option : false_option)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have different approaches according to your requirements

#### Multiple Conditions inside `<View>`

```
  _renderMultipleCondition = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Insert Multiple Condition </Text>
        {item.categoryName == "image" && <Component passProps={item.item} />}
        {item.categoryName == "video" && (
          <View>
            <Text>Condition meet</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

### Other Way

#### Using Ternary approach

```
_renderTernary = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Using ternary Condition </Text>
        {item.categoryName == "image" ? (
          <Component passProps={item.item} />
        ) : (
          <View>
            <Text>Else portion </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the checking it before return the value.
 For example:

```
render() {
 let viewA = null
 const { status } = this.state
 if(status === "En attente") {
    viewA = (<View><Text>Hello attente!</Text></View>)      
 }else if(status === 'En cours") {
   viewA = (<View><Text>Hello cours!</Text></View>)  
 }else {
   viewA = (<View><Text>Hello something else!</Text></View>)  
 }
 return viewA
}
```

So, it is pretty simple. Hope it helps you. :))

Comment: With this solution, in real code, for small changes you have to code a lot! Am I right?